# Get KeyValuePair given Key

Tags: c#, dictionary, key-value

Given a `String` that is a `Key` contained in `Dictionary<String, List<String>>`, how do I retrieve the `KeyValuePair<String, List<String>>` that corresponds to that `Key`?

Comment: List<String> values = dict["myKey"];

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but, why not just call directly oDico["Key"] to retreive the list ?*

Comment: @jdweng & Mathieu - OP needs the "KeyValuePair<String, List<String>>" for the selected key, not just the List<String>

Comment: Developer : OP already has the key.  Read the posting again.

Comment: That's why I comment, for ask a question that maybe will reveal a misanderstunding about a concept. Personnaly I don't see any reason to to deal with KVP, maybe I'm passing beside a great concept ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with other answers using `FirstOrDefault` is that it will sequentially search the entire dictionary until it finds a match, and you lose the benefit of having a hashed lookup. It seems more sensible if you really need a `KeyValuePair` to just build one, like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
        {
            ["key1"] = new List<string> { "1" },
            ["key2"] = new List<string> { "2" },
            ["key3"] = new List<string> { "3" },
        };

        var key = "key2";

        var keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(key, dictionary[key]);

        Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair.Value[0]);
    }
}
```

(with credit to David Pine for the original code in his answer).

Here's a fiddle for that: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zg8x7s

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want the value associated with the key, for example:

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>> dictionary = GetDictionary();
var value = dictionary["key"];
```

But you can use `Linq` to get the entire `KeyValuePair`:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    ["key1"] = new List<string> { "1" },
    ["key2"] = new List<string> { "2" },
    ["key3"] = new List<string> { "3" },
};

var keyValuePair = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == "key2");

Console.WriteLine(keyValuePair?.Value[0]); // Prints "2"
```

Here is a [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rVRxzd).